# Installing Numpy for Python 3.3 on Mac Mavericks OS 10.9

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, osx-mavericks, python-3.3

I am trying to install numpy (so that I can run matplotlibs) for python 3.3 on Mac Mavericks. I have a Windows machine and was able to install everything correctly by simply downloading the .exe files. However, I am very new to the Mac world, and have never installed anything via command line before.

I have downloaded Anaconda and also XCode.

I have tried:

```
pip install numpy
```

and I get the following output:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

It looks like it has 2.7 installed already, but I want 3.3! So, next I tried:

```
pip-3.3 install numpy
```

and I get the following output:

```
pip-3.3: command not found
```

I have tried to use anaconda after these have failed (having never used anaconda before):

```
conda create -n myenv python=3
conda install -n myenv numpy scipy matplotlib ipython
```

After everything was said and done, I got this message:

```
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /Users/username/anaconda/envs/myenv:
#
ipython                   2.2.0                    py34_1  
matplotlib                1.3.1                np18py34_1  
numpy                     1.8.2                    py34_0  
scipy                     0.14.0               np18py34_0
```

This didn't work either when I attempted to import matplotlib into Python 3.3. It appears to me that this has not installed numpy for 3.3, but for 3.4.

So, I installed Python 3.4. However, it looks like there are compatibility issues between matplotlib and 3.4, so back to 3.3... Additionally, I could not import numpy into 3.4 anyway.

A number of the topics on here where people posted similar problems had OS Lion. As a new Mac person, I can't seem to follow those directions because my version is the newer Mavericks. I looked here, for example: [NumPy in IDLE (Python 3.3.2) on Mac OSx 10.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819227/numpy-in-idle-python-3-3-2-on-mac-osx-10-8)

When I type

```
which python
```

into the terminal, I get

```
/Users/username/anaconda/bin/python
```

I do not get

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3
```

like the user in that topic suggested I should. In fact, the /Library folder appears to be hard to find on Mavericks..  But, I figured out how to make ~/Library visible.  I next

```
cd Library/Frameworks
ls
```

and saw:

```
EWSMac-GC.framework
```

There was no Python.framework.  At this points, I feel like I should have that directory in order to continue.  Perhaps not.  I am lost at how to continue at this point, and if anyone has any suggestions, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I now have numpy installed correctly for Python 3.4, but not Python 3.3.

What I did from terminal:

```
cd ../..
pwd
```

output:

```
/
```

commands:

```
cd usr/local/bin
ls
```

output:

```
2to3            python3-32      pythonw3.3
2to3-3.3        python3-config      pythonw3.3-32
2to3-3.4        python3.3       pyvenv
brew            python3.3-32        pyvenv-3.3
easy_install-3.4    python3.3-config    pyvenv-3.4
idle3           python3.3m      tclselect
idle3.3         python3.3m-config   tclsh
idle3.4         python3.4       tclsh8.6
pip3            python3.4-32        tclvfse
pip3.4          python3.4-config    teacup
pydoc3          python3.4m      wish
pydoc3.3        python3.4m-config   wish8.6
pydoc3.4        pythonw3
python3         pythonw3-32
```

commands:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

There was a lot of output, many lines that looked like:

```
 Downloading numpy-1.8.2-cp34-cp34m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_
```

And then this output:

```
10_9_x86_64.whl (12.0MB): 12.0MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: numpy
Successfully installed numpy
Cleaning up...
```

This command installed numpy for 3.4, and not 3.3, as intended. As stated above, I now have both on my system. I don't know if it would have installed for 3.3 if I had completely uninstalled 3.4 first.

I tried to install numpy for 3.3:

```
pip3 install numpy python3.3
```

output:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /Library/Framework/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Downloading/unpacking python3.3
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python3.3
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python3.3
```

I tried importing numpy from python 3.4 and it worked. However, my primary goal was to use matplotlib.  I attempted to install matplotlib from the command line.

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

This worked, and now I can use matplotlib in python 3.4 and IDLE for 3.4.

Unfortunately, this doesn't satisfy requirements for Python 3.3... But for now, 3.4 is probably OK too.

Answer (score 0):

install python (matplotlib numpy integrating and more ...) through Homebrew, an installer libraries